# How to solve CS0246 The type or namespace name 'TypeNameSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard, easynetq

I have a .net framework class library project which is absolutely working fine with the .net framework projects, Now I need to refer it in .net core application also. so I am trying to create a new .net standard project and copied all the .cs files to this project from the existing project. and started fixing the compilation errors. I have fixed many but still getting a few.

```
_rabbitBus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[queueName].ConnectionString,
    serviceRegister => serviceRegister.Register<ISerializer>(
        serviceProvider => new JsonSerializer(new TypeNameSerializer())
    )
);
```

I am getting the below error with the code mentioned above.

> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'TypeNameSerializer' could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So How to solve this issue?

Note: I have fixed the compilation error b using this code `new JsonSerializer(new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings())` , but I don't know whether its correct way or not, So please guide me how to solve this issue.

Comment: `TypeNameSerializer` is not a BCL class. Where does it come from?

Comment: It's in easynetq, I have added that as tag in my question

Comment: You might want to check the version of the EasyNetQ you are using in .NET framework and .NET Core. Class `JsonSerializer` in latest version of EasyNetQ does not have constructor which accepts `TypeNameSerializer` also latest version of EasyNetQ library does not have any class name `TypeNameSerializer`. [EasyNetQ Repo](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ) and [JsonSerializer class](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/develop/Source/EasyNetQ/JsonSerializer.cs)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you I missed this point, please add this as answer

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  I added the version 5.2.0, I have to downgrade it to 1.1.4.506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like different versions of EasyNetQ are being used in .NET Framework and .NET Core.

The latest version of EasyNetQ does not have any class with name `TypeNameSerializer` that's why you are getting this error.

Also class `JsonSerializer` in latest version of EasyNetQ does no have a constructor which accepts `TypeNameSerializer` as a parameter.

You can refer to [Git Repo of EasyNetQ](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ)  and also the [Source Code of JsonSerializer class](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/develop/Source/EasyNetQ/JsonSerializer.cs).

You need to use the same version of EasyNetQ in .NET Core as it is being used in .NET Framework project in order to use `TypeNameSerializer`.